# How can I convert a dictionary into a Pandas DataFrame with specific keys as column names in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary as follows:

```
D = {'mark': [['height', 7], ['weight', 70]],
     'david': [['height', 8], ['weight', 80]],
     'john': [['height', 9], ['weight', 90]]}
print (D)
```

I wanted to get the pandas dataframe into this form:

```
   names  height  weight
0   mark       7      70
1  david       8      80
2   john       9      90
```

I tried as follows.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(D)
print (df)
```

However, it produces a wrong result below.

```
           mark         david          john
0   [height, 7]   [height, 8]   [height, 9]
1  [weight, 70]  [weight, 80]  [weight, 90]
```

## Edit:

What if dictionary has not same number of values as follows?

```
D2 = {'mark': [['height', 7], ['weight', 70]],
     'david': [['height', 8], ['weight', 80]],
     'john': [['height', 9]]}
print (D2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({k: dict(v) for (k,v) in D.items()}).T.reset_index(names="names")
```

Output :

```
print(df)

   names  height  weight
0   mark       7      70
1  david       8      80
2   john       9      90
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.from_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) with [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = (pd.DataFrame.from_dict({k: dict(v) for k, v in D.items()}, orient='index')
        .reset_index(names="names"))
print (df)
   names  height  weight
0   mark       7      70
1  david       8      80
2   john       9      90
```

---

```
df = (pd.DataFrame.from_dict({k: dict(v) for k, v in D2.items()}, orient='index')
        .reset_index(names="names"))
print (df)
   names  height  weight
0   mark       7    70.0
1  david       8    80.0
2   john       9     NaN
```

Comment: What if dictionary has not same number of values as in case of D2 in my edit ?

Comment: @mark - Then is created `NaN`s

Comment: yes, would like to create dataframe with NaN in such case.

Comment: @mark - both solutions created NaNs ;)

Comment: yeah, I see, both worked with D2 as well.